# How do you make Elementor changes visible without pressing CTRL + F5?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm currently using WordPress with Elementor to build a new website.
I'm creating the website in Chrome, and viewing the website in Firefox.

When I make changes in Elementor in Chrome, and update/publish the changes, I have to press CTRL+F5 in Firefox to see the changes.

So Elementor must be updating a CSS file, with the same filename.

What can I do to ensure my Elementor changes are visible to everyone, without them having to press CTRL+F5 (force refresh) to see the changes?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you shoud go to Elementor ->Tools->Update CSS/Style (something like that).
If you are using a caching plugin, make sure to "clear the cache" too.

Comment: The Elementor > Tools > Regenerate CSS just regenerates the CSS file with the same filename. So other people viewing the site won't see the changes unless they do a CTRL+F5. I want my Elementor changes to be visible to everyone viewing the site, without having to press CTRL+F5

Comment: i dont think there is any need of file name change. its all about styles, which you can regenerate through the path mentioned. if it doesnt work, its probably due to caching plugins.

Comment: i cant think of anything else, please share your solution if you found one

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the cache duration in .htacces

But I would recommend deactivating this setting after development.  Otherwise this can have negative consequences for your SEO (PageSpeed).

```
# BEGIN Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 300 seconds"

</IfModule>
# END Browser Cache
```